# How do I export my project in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I need to export my Android Studio project to an Android phone. I've generated a signed APK already but I don't know what to do after this. What else do I need to do to export my project?

Comment: read this https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device and delete the question please

Comment: cant delete it so

Comment: Upload it to the Play Store and then install it from there. See https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469?hl=de

Answer (score 0):

Install it. Look for the apk file in the project folder and transfer it to your phone and click it.
Another way, connect your android phone to your laptop and click on instant Run.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't called exporting, it's called installing.

By default, the APK should be under

```
app/release/
```

in your project directory, as `app-release.apk`.

You can use the Android Studio terminal tab (check the bottom toolbar) to install it directly:

```
adb install -r app/release/app-release.apk
```

Comment: So if I have my phone connected, that command will install it on my phone?

Comment: Yes. You need ADB enabled on your phone.

Comment: Do I need to do anything on my computer besides put the command in?

Comment: It should run fine as long as you have the Android SDK installed, which you should. You can look up tutorials on using ADB for more details.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Android Emulator, then you can directly run and check your app contents. 
Or
If you want your app to run on your phone, then go to the app folder of your Android project 
Directory : app/release/release.apk
Connect your data cable and move that release.apk in your phone directory and install that apk file in your Android phone.